# Css table with scalable div on the sides

Tags: html, css

I have a central div that have 4 others divs arrount it (top, right, left, bottom).

**Top** and **Bottom** divs are suposed to be fixed. They don't have to increase neither height nor width.

**Right** and **left** divs are ONLY suposed to increase its width.

How?

The "content" div (central) is a table that can have as many rows as the user wants. Then, I want to increase or decrease the height of the **left** and **right** divs depending on the height of the "content".

**I want to automatically do that .**

How can I do that?

I have created an example with what I have done, without success.

https://jsfiddle.net/y6ad2crg/4/

```
<div class="pantalla">
    <div  class=" pantallaSup"></div>

        <div class="pantallaEsq"></div>
        <div class="pantallaDre"></div>

        <div class="interiorPantalla">
            content<br>
            aaa<br>
            bbb<br>
            ccc<br>
            ddd<br>
            eee
        </div>
        <div class="pantallaInf"></div>
</div>
```

---

The result I want to get is that:

[image: example]

What am I doing wrong?

Maybe just changing little things in css it may be done, or maybe my html is wrong designed...

Comment: well this is not rather preferable way to design a website, because you're using absolute units all over the place

Comment: @MarkoMackic I know that I should use % instead of absolute units, but I don't know exactly how to change it. If I use % it will become responsive and I don't want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change u code
https://jsfiddle.net/p7haf3oo/

```css
.pantalla {
  /*position: relative;*/
  display: block;
  width: 690px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.pantallaSup {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.pantallaEsq {
  width: 69.4px;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

.pantallaDre {
  width: 69.4px;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.pantallaInf {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.interiorPantalla {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pantalla">
  <div class="pantallaSup"></div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="pantallaEsq"></div>
    <div class="interiorPantalla">
      content
      <br> aaa
      <br> bbb
      <br> ccc
      <br> ddd
      <br> eee
    </div>
    <div class="pantallaDre"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pantallaInf"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. As @Marko Mackic said, would it be complicated to change absolute units to %? Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have coded what you're looking for -https://jsfiddle.net/Shuaso/vpmn3LLv/

I removed all the unnecessary divs and used CSS borders and background colors to achieve the same effect. You can alter the content in the "content" div and see the dynamic styles. Here's the code:

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.content {
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-right: 20px solid green;
  background-color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```